# How can you get internet on a train?

Tags: internet, connection

There are some rail road companies offering an internet connection to their customers. How can they do it? What kind of internet connection can they have on board a moving vehicle?

- Satellite connection? I think the train movement will displace a mounted dish and it also will have to be constantly moved around to find the satellite as the train makes turns. Speed isn't greater either.
- GSM connection - EDGE, UMTS, CSD? 3G coverage often is not an option in rural areas where train goes. These kinds of technologies doesn't offer good speed.
- WiMax? Wikipedia article on it says it could provide 40Mbps for long distances. Is that what they use mostly?
- Some kind of power line internet carrier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here in Canada, the main train service (Via Rail) uses WiMAX. You can read some details about a train WiMAX setup [here](http://wifinetnews.com/archives/2006/07/caltrain_tries_wimax_on_train.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here in Sweden the trains have satellite as main connection backed up with 3G and GSM. My guess is that this is the common way for all rail roads.

[Source in English](http://www.sj.se/sj/jsp/polopoly.jsp?d=222&a=69523&l=en)

> Most of the time you surf via satellite and then you get most bandwidth. But so that you can surf without interruption we run a number of parallel links (both 3G and GSM). So while the train is driving, the system is always looking for the best connection.